# Helper not available in the view

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am migrating from 1.3 to 2.0.6 and have the following problem:

> Notice (8): Undefined variable: session [APP/View/Users/login.ctp, line 2]
>
> Fatal error: Call to a member function flash() on a non-object in login.ctp on line 2

Why is there a problem accessing the session helper?

Comment: Are you possibly testing a variable that hasn't been defined previously.

like `if($session)...` without first having set `$session = false` or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### That's not how to use helpers

> Notice (8): Undefined variable: session [APP/View/Users/login.ctp, line 2]
>
> Fatal error: Call to a member function flash() on a non-object in login.ctp

Whilst it's not in the question your `login.ctp` template looks something like this:

```
<?php
echo $session>flash(); # line 2
```

That's *not* [how helpers are expected to be used in CakePHP 2.x](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/helpers.html#using-your-helper):

> you can use [the helper] in your views by accessing an object named after the
>   helper:
>
> ```
> <!-- make a link using the new helper -->
> <?php echo $this->Link->makeEdit('Change this Recipe', '/recipes/edit/5'); ?>
> ```

The code you're looking for is:

```
# echo $session->flash(); # wrong
echo $this->Session->flash(); # right
```

Note also that `Session` needs to be in the [controller `$helpers` array](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html#components-helpers-and-uses).

In 1.2 and earlier versions of CakePHP helpers were expected to be variables, [this changed but was still supported in 1.3](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/appendices/new-features-in-cakephp-1-3.html#view-helpers). If your 1.3 CakePHP application has been using helpers in this way, it has been relying on backwards-compatibility with earlier versions. In 2.0 helpers are not variables, and only possible to access as a view class property. Be sure to read [the migration guides](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/appendices.html) - for more information on what has changed.

Comment: Thank you! this solved my issue. I am in the process of upgrading from 1.3 to 2.0.6 so I am just trying to sort out all the bugs

Comment: That's an odd version to upgrade to - I recommend you to upgrade to the latest 2.x release.

Comment: Yeah I am getting there but it was really tough to try to go straight from 1.3 to the latest release so I am doing it in two steps.

Comment: Please re-read my above comment. You will find almost no difference upgrading from 1.3 to 2.0, 2.7 or (if you're reading this in the future, whatever is the current 2.x point release).